# Problem with BERT, XLNET Transformer Pipline and GPU acceleration with Flask API

Tags: flask, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am beginner in the field of machine learning and would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

I have learned XLNet and BERT Transformer models, which both solve the text classification problem. Both artificial networks work well and I don’t see any problem while using them on my GPU and CPU as well directly from my python code.

Few weeks ago I decided to implement a simple API to access the learned models and I have implemented a simple Flask application that uses Worker and runs in both synchronous and asynchronous modes (https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/). The application works good and I am able to access the models to let them classify the input text (the text is send using POST request in JSON format), but there is one problem which I am not able to solve.

The API works without any problem only during the synchronous mode (both GPU and CPU versions). The problem appears when I tried to put the same code from my CPU to my GPU and run it again asynchronously.
The problem appears when I try to access model’s predictions (its result, see `ret` variable).

This happens for both the Transformer Pipline and for my bert model in `eval()` mode. In case when I try to access model's result the Python returned me (see the `exec_job` function)
`ret is None; TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and I am not able to access `ret['status']`, because the `ret` is None.

When I delete the parts of code putting my model and created tensors on GPU (I just deleted `.to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)` parts) - everything works fine (but in this case my model is located on CPU and the evaluation takes much more time).

```
# This code runs in __init__
self._model.to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID) 

# These lines are executed during evaluation         
inputs = torch.tensor(input_ids).to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)
segments = torch.tensor(segments).to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)
masks = torch.tensor(attention_masks).to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)
```

I tied to debug my code and notice that the function `self._process_tokenized_text(sentence)` executed successfully but the code after GPU parts not executed at all and even my `print()` code does not do anything.

Simplified code below.

Asynchronous function which runs the function `exec_job`

```
    @app.route('/api/text/check-json-async', methods=['POST'])
    @auth.login_required
    def check_json_async():
        request_data = request.get_json()
        text=request_data['data']
        job = q.enqueue_call(
            func='aijob.exec_job', args=(text,True,), result_ttl=60
        )
        global callbackURL
        ret={"text":text,"callbackURL":callbackURL,"jobID":job.get_id(),"status":"queued"}
        return jsonify(ret)
```

`exec_job` function which calls _aiprocess function and access the AI core

```
    # The function whitch publish the main functionality of this layer
    def exec_job(text, async_parm):
        # Evaluate text
        ret = _aiprocess(text)
        # Save classificated result --> THIS CODE FAILS ONLY ON GPU MODE BECAUSE the RET is NONE
        _savePredictedResult(ret['status'] == STATUS, ret)
        if async_parm is True:
            import pickle
            f = open('callbackURL.pckl', 'rb')
            callbackURL = pickle.load(f)
            f.close()
            print(ret)
            print(callbackURL)
            requests.post(callbackURL, json=ret)
        return ret
```

The AI core the `_aiprocess` function

```
   def _aiprocess(self, sentence):
        if sentence is not None:
            #function working on CPU successfully returns the result
            input_ids, attention_masks, segments = self._process_tokenized_text(sentence)
            # print works as well
            print(input_ids, attention_masks, segments)

            inputs = torch.tensor(input_ids).to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)
            segments = torch.tensor(segments).to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)
            masks = torch.tensor(attention_masks).to(_configuration.GPU_DEVICE_ID)
            # This code do nothing and when I try to access the predictions array there is nothing but only in GPU mode
            print(inputs)
            # Tracking variables 
            predictions = []
            
            # Predict 
            with torch.no_grad():
                outputs = self._model(input_ids = inputs,token_type_ids=segments, input_mask = masks)
                for tmptuple in outputs[:1]:
                    tmp_array = torch.nn.functional.softmax(tmptuple, dim=1).cpu().numpy()
                    for result in tmp_array:
                        predictions.append(self._resultPrediction(result))                                   
            return predictions[0]
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Thank you so much and I am sorry for my bad English.